# mysql.connector.errors.InternalError: Unread result found datanasabah

Tags: python, mysql-connector

`Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py", line 1921, in **call**
return self.func(*args)
File "C:\Users\Windows 11\Documents\semester 2 sisfo\tubes apk alpro\pages.py", line 38, in login_nasabah
datanasabah = cek_rekeningDanPin()
File "C:\Users\Windows 11\Documents\semester 2 sisfo\tubes apk alpro\pages.py", line 30, in cek_rekeningDanPin
mycursor.execute(query, val)
File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor_cext.py", line 303, in execute
self._cnx.handle_unread_result()
File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 921, in handle_unread_result
raise InternalError("Unread result found")
mysql.connector.errors.InternalError: Unread result found

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import font
import random
import mysql.connector
from tkinter import messagebox

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    port=3307,
    user="root",
    password="",
    database="sistem_atm"
)
mycursor = mydb.cursor()


def cek_pin():
    pin = pin_entry.get()
    query = "SELECT * FROM nasabah WHERE  pin =%s "
    val = (pin,)
    mycursor.execute(query, val)
    result = mycursor.fetchone()
    return result

def cek_rekeningDanPin():
    pin = pin_entry.get()
    norekening = norekening_entry.get()
    query = "SELECT * FROM nasabah WHERE  no_rek=%s and pin =%s "
    val = (norekening,pin,)
    mycursor.execute(query, val)
    hasil= mycursor.fetchone()
    
    return hasil


def login_nasabah():
    global datanasabah
    datanasabah = cek_rekeningDanPin()
    if datanasabah:
        login_success()
    else:
        messagebox.showerror(
            "Login Failed", "pin is incorrect")

def pin_NominalTransfer():
    result = cek_pin()
    if result:
        transaksi()
    else:
        messagebox.showerror(
            "Login Failed", "pin is incorrect")

def pin_transaksi():
    result = cek_pin()
    if result:
        Data_transaksi()
    else:
        messagebox.showerror(
            "Login Failed", "pin is incorrect")


def loginapps():
    global root
    root = tk.Tk()

    screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()

    root_width = 500
    root_height = 600

    x_screen = (screen_width - root_width) // 2
    y_screen = (screen_height - root_height) // 2

    root.resizable(False, False)
    root.geometry(f"{root_width}x{root_height}+{x_screen}+{y_screen}")

    global tampilan_frame
    tampilan_frame = tk.LabelFrame(root, text="")
    tampilan_frame.pack(pady=30)

    global custom_font
    custom_font = font.Font(family='Calibri', size=12)

    tampilan = tk.Label(
        tampilan_frame, text='Selamat Datang! Silahkan Masukkan PIN Anda', font=custom_font)
    tampilan.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
    
    global label_login
    label_login = tk.Label(
        tampilan_frame, text='Masukkan NoRekening dan PIN:', font=custom_font)
    label_login.pack(padx=180, pady=200)

    
    global norekening_entry
    norekening_entry = tk.Entry(tampilan_frame, font=custom_font)
    norekening_entry.place(x=145, y=270)

    global pin_entry
    pin_entry = tk.Entry(tampilan_frame, font=custom_font, show='*')
    pin_entry.place(x=155, y=300)

    button_login = tk.Button(
        tampilan_frame, text='  Login  ', font=custom_font, command=login_nasabah)
    button_login.place(x=200, y=320)

    reset_button = tk.Button(
        tampilan_frame, text='  Daftar Rekening  ', font=custom_font, command=daftarRekening)
    reset_button.place(x=165, y=370)

    root.mainloop()


def daftarRekening():
    tampilan_frame.pack_forget()

    global daftar_labelframe
    daftar_labelframe = tk.LabelFrame(root, text="")
    daftar_labelframe.pack(pady=30)

    daftar_label = tk.Label(
        daftar_labelframe, text='Silahkan isi Data diri anda ', font=custom_font)
    daftar_label.pack(padx=120, pady=10)

    nama = tk.Label(daftar_labelframe,
                    text='Nama Lengkap : ', font=custom_font)
    nama.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
    global nama1_entry
    nama1_entry = tk.Entry(daftar_labelframe)
    nama1_entry.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

    nama = tk.Label(daftar_labelframe, text='NIK : ', font=custom_font)
    nama.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
    global nik1_entry
    nik1_entry = tk.Entry(daftar_labelframe)
    nik1_entry.pack(padx=30, pady=30)

    global pin1_entry
    nama1 = tk.Label(daftar_labelframe, text='PIN : ', font=custom_font)
    nama1.pack(padx=10, pady=0)
    pin1_entry = tk.Entry(daftar_labelframe)
    pin1_entry.pack(padx=40, pady=40)

    global simpan1_button
    simpan1_button = tk.Button(
        daftar_labelframe, text='Simpan Data', command=kartuDigital)
    simpan1_button.pack(padx=50, pady=50)


def kartuDigital():
    daftar_labelframe.pack_forget()

    global kartu_labelframe
    kartu_labelframe = tk.LabelFrame(root, text="")
    kartu_labelframe.pack(pady=30)

    berhasil_label = tk.Label(
        kartu_labelframe, text='Anda Berhasil Daftar!', font=custom_font, anchor='w')
    berhasil_label.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

    no_kartu = str(random.randint(100000000000, 999999999999))
    no_kartu = ' '.join([no_kartu[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(no_kartu), 4)])
    nokartu = tk.Label(
        kartu_labelframe, text='No Kartu Anda: ' + no_kartu, font=custom_font)
    nokartu.pack(padx=30, pady=10)

    global no_rekening
    no_rekening = str(random.randint(1000000000, 9999999999))
    noRekening = tk.Label(
        kartu_labelframe, text='No Rekening Anda: ' + no_rekening, font=custom_font)
    noRekening.pack(padx=30, pady=20)

    kartu1_label = tk.Label(
        kartu_labelframe, text=f'Nama Lengkap: {nama1_entry.get()}', font=custom_font)
    kartu1_label.pack(padx=10, pady=30)

    kartu2_label = tk.Label(
        kartu_labelframe, text=f'NIK: {nik1_entry.get()}', font=custom_font)
    kartu2_label.pack(padx=30, pady=40)

    global kartu3_label
    kartu3_label = tk.Label(
        kartu_labelframe, text=f'PIN: {pin1_entry.get()}', font=custom_font)
    kartu3_label.pack(padx=30, pady=40)

    button_kartu = tk.Button(
        kartu_labelframe, text=' Selesai ', font=custom_font, command=backtologin)
    button_kartu.pack(padx=30, pady=30)

    # kode untuk insert ke database
    query = "INSERT INTO nasabah VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
    data = (no_rekening, no_kartu, nama1_entry.get(),
            nik1_entry.get(), pin1_entry.get())
    mycursor.execute(query, data)
    mydb.commit()


def backtologin():
    kartu_labelframe.pack_forget()
    tampilan_frame.pack()


def login_success():
    tampilan_frame.pack_forget()  # Menghilangkan frame lama
    print(datanasabah)
    # Membuat frame baru  halaman selanjutnya
    global new_labelframe
    new_labelframe = tk.LabelFrame(root, text="")
    new_labelframe.pack(pady=30)

    # Menambahkan isi halaman selanjutnya
    new_label1 = tk.Label(
        new_labelframe, text='Pilih Transaksi yang anda inginkan Tekan Cancel untuk pembatalan', font=custom_font)
    new_label1.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

    button_transfer = tk.Button(
        new_labelframe, text='  <-- Transfer -->  ', font=custom_font, command=transfer_window)
    button_transfer.pack(padx=60, pady=35)

    button_penarikantunai = tk.Button(
        new_labelframe, text='  <-- Tarik/Setor Tunai -->  ', font=custom_font, command=tariksetorTunai)
    button_penarikantunai.pack(padx=60, pady=35)

    button_Informasisaldo = tk.Button(
        new_labelframe, text='  <-- Informasi Saldo -->  ', font=custom_font,)
    button_Informasisaldo.pack(padx=60, pady=35)

    button_Cancel = tk.Button(
        new_labelframe, text='  Cancel  ', font=custom_font, command=closeProgram)
    button_Cancel.pack(padx=60, pady=50)

    #tampilan menekan tramsfer dan menjalankan windwow baru 
def transfer_window():
    new_labelframe.pack_forget()  

    global transfer_labelframe
    transfer_labelframe = tk.LabelFrame(root, text="")
    transfer_labelframe.pack(pady=30)

    transfer_label = tk.Label(
        transfer_labelframe, text='ATM Transfer Pilih Bank Tujuan Transfer', font=custom_font)
    transfer_label.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

    button_BRI = tk.Button(
        transfer_labelframe, text='   <-- BRI -->  ', font=custom_font, command=bankBRI)
    button_BRI.pack(padx=110, pady=60)

    button_Banklain = tk.Button(
        transfer_labelframe, text='  <-- BANK LAIN -->  ', font=custom_font, command=banklain)
    button_Banklain.pack(padx=110, pady=60)

    button_DaftarKontak = tk.Button(
        transfer_labelframe, text='  <-- DAFTAR KODE BANK -->  ', font=custom_font,command=daftarKodeBank)
    button_DaftarKontak.pack(padx=110, pady=60)


    #tampilan menekan BRI dan membuka window baru di halaman bri
def bankBRI():
    transfer_labelframe.pack_forget() 

    
    global bankBRI_labelframe
    bankBRI_labelframe = tk.LabelFrame(root, text="")
    bankBRI_labelframe.pack(pady=30)


    bri_label = tk.Label(
        bankBRI_labelframe, text='Silahkan Isi No Rekening Bank Yang Dituju', font=custom_font)
    bri_label.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

    global norekening_entry
    norekening_label = tk.Label(
        bankBRI_labelframe, text='Masukan No Rekening : ', font=custom_font, anchor='center')
    norekening_label.pack(padx=120, pady=120)
    norekening_entry = tk.Entry(bankBRI_labelframe)
    norekening_entry.place(x=140, y=240)

    button_enter = tk.Button(
        bankBRI_labelframe, text='  Enter  ', font=custom_font, command=nominalTransfer)
    button_enter.pack(padx=110, pady=60)

    # menambahkan rekening tujuan dan beralih ke nominal transfer 
def nominalTransfer():
    bankBRI_labelframe.pack_forget()

    global nominal_labelframe
    nominal_labelframe = tk.LabelFrame(root, text="")
    nominal_labelframe.pack(pady=30)

    nominalframe = tk.Label(
        nominal_labelframe, text='Masukan Jumlah Nominal yang akan di transfer', font=custom_font)
    nominalframe.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

    nominalframeRp = tk.Label(
        nominal_labelframe, text='Rp', font=custom_font, anchor='center')
    nominalframeRp.pack(padx=120, pady=40)
    global nominal_entry
    nominal_entry = tk.Entry(nominal_labelframe)
    nominal_entry.pack(padx=120, pady=20)

    label_login = tk.Label(
        nominal_labelframe, text='Masukkan PIN:', font=custom_font, anchor='s')
    label_login.pack(padx=110, pady=120)
    global pin_entry
    pin_entry = tk.Entry(nominal_labelframe, show='*')
    pin_entry.place(x=120, y=360)

    button_benar = tk.Button(
        nominal_labelframe, text='  <-- Tekan jika benar -->  ', font=custom_font, command=pin_NominalTransfer )
    button_benar.place(x=90, y=390)

    button_salah = tk.Button(
        nominal_labelframe, text='  <-- Reset -->  ', font=custom_font, command=reset_Pin)
    button_salah.place(x=130, y=430)


def reset_Pin():
    pin_entry.delete(0, tk.END)

    #beralih ke detail  transaksi 
def transaksi ():
    nominal_labelframe.pack_forget()

    global benar_labelframe
    benar_labelframe = tk.LabelFrame(root, text="")
    benar_labelframe.pack(pady=30)

    benarlframe = tk.Label(
        benar_labelframe, text='Masukan Pin Anda Jika data transaksi sudah benar', font=custom_font)
    benarlframe.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
    
    rekeningSayaframe = tk.Label(
        benar_labelframe, text=f'No Rekening Anda: {datanasabah[0]}', font=custom_font, anchor='center')
    rekeningSayaframe.pack(padx=10, pady=20)

    rekeningTujuanframe = tk.Label(
        benar_labelframe, text=f'No Rekening Tujuan: {norekening_entry.get()}', font=custom_font, anchor='center')
    rekeningTujuanframe.pack(padx=10, pady=20, )

    jumlahtransaksiframe = tk.Label(
        benar_labelframe, text=f'Jumlah Transaksi: {nominal_entry.get()}', font=custom_font, anchor='center')
    jumlahtransaksiframe.pack(padx=10, pady=20, )

    masukanpinframe = tk.Label(
        benar_labelframe, text='Masukan Pin : ', font=custom_font)
    masukanpinframe.pack(padx=10, pady=40)
    
    pin_entry = tk.Entry(benar_labelframe, font=custom_font, show='*')
    pin_entry.pack(padx=10, pady=30)

    button_enter = tk.Button(
        benar_labelframe, text='  Enter  ', font=custom_font, anchor='s', command=pin_transaksi)
    button_enter.pack(padx=10, pady=15)

    # kode untuk insert ke database
    queryku = "INSERT INTO data_transaksi VALUES (%s, %s, %s,%s)"
    val = (datanasabah[2],datanasabah[0],
                    norekening_entry.get(),nominal_entry.get())
    mycursor.execute(queryku, val)
    mydb.commit()

    #beralih ke data transaksi dan transaksi berhasil di lakukan pada halaman BRI  
def Data_transaksi():
    benar_labelframe.pack_forget()

    global enter_labelframe
    enter_labelframe = tk.LabelFrame(root, text="")
    enter_labelframe.pack(pady=30)

    enterframe = tk.Label(enter_labelframe, text='ATM',
                          font=custom_font, anchor='w')
    enterframe.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

    enterframe2 = tk.Label(
        enter_labelframe, text='Transaksi Anda Berhasil Dilaksanakan', font=custom_font, anchor='center')
    enterframe2.pack(padx=10, pady=20)
    enterframe3 = tk.Label(
        enter_labelframe, text='Terimakasi Atas Kepercayaan Anda', font=custom_font)
    enterframe3.pack(padx=10, pady=20)
    enterframe3 = tk.Label(
        enter_labelframe, text='Transaksi Lagi ? ', font=custom_font)
    enterframe3.pack(padx=10, pady=20)

    global buttonenter1
    buttonenter1 = tk.Button(enter_labelframe, text='ya',
                             font=custom_font, anchor='s', command=backtoMenu)
    buttonenter1.pack(padx=50, pady=50)

    buttonenter2 = tk.Button(enter_labelframe, text='tidak',
                             font=custom_font, anchor='s', command=closeProgram)
    buttonenter2.pack(padx=50, pady=40)

    #kembali ke tampilan window menu login 
def backtoMenu():
    enter_labelframe.pack_forget()
    login_success()

    #menutup program
def closeProgram():
    root.destroy()


def banklain():
    transfer_labelframe.pack_forget()

    global banklainframe
    banklainframe = tk.LabelFrame(root, text="")
    banklainframe.pack(pady=30)

    banklain_label = tk.Label(
        banklainframe, text=' Pilih Bank Tujuan ', font=custom_font, anchor='w')
    banklain_label.pack(padx=30, pady=10)

    button_Bni = tk.Button(
        banklainframe, text='<-- BNI -->', font=custom_font, command=menuMANDIRI)
    button_Bni.pack(padx=80, pady=10)

    button_mandiri = tk.Button(
        banklainframe, text='<-- MANDIRI -->', font=custom_font, command=menuMANDIRI)
    button_mandiri.pack(padx=80, pady=15)

    button_syariah = tk.Button(
        banklainframe, text='<-- SYARIAH -->', font=custom_font, command=menuMANDIRI)
    button_syariah.pack(padx=80, pady=20)

    button_danamon = tk.Button(
        banklainframe, text='<-- DANAMON -->', font=custom_font, command=menuMANDIRI)
    button_danamon.pack(padx=80, pady=25)

    button_permata = tk.Button(
        banklainframe, text='<-- PERMATA BANK -->', font=custom_font, command=menuMANDIRI)
    button_permata.pack(padx=80, pady=30)

    button_kembali = tk.Button(
        banklainframe, text='<-- KEMBALI -->', font=custom_font, command=backtomenlogin)
    button_kembali.pack(padx=80, pady=35)


def menuMANDIRI():
    banklainframe.pack_forget()
    bankBRI()


def backtomenlogin():
    banklainframe.pack_forget()
    login_success()

def daftarKodeBank():
    new_labelframe.pack_forget()

    global daftarKodeframe 
    daftarKodeframe=tk.LabelFrame(root,text='')
    daftarKodeframe.pack(pady=30)

    
    daftarKode_label = tk.Label(
        daftarKodeframe, text=' Pilih Kode Bank Tujuan anda ', font=custom_font, anchor='w')
    daftarKode_label.pack(padx=30, pady=10)

    daftarKodeBRI_label = tk.Label(
        daftarKodeframe, text=' BRI  : 333', font=custom_font, anchor='w')
    daftarKodeBRI_label.pack(padx=80, pady=10)

    
    daftarKodeBNI_label = tk.Label(
        daftarKodeframe, text=' BNI  : 444', font=custom_font, anchor='w')
    daftarKodeBNI_label.pack(padx=80, pady=15)

    
    daftarKodeMANDIRI_label = tk.Label(
        daftarKodeframe, text=' MANDRI  : 555', font=custom_font, anchor='w')
    daftarKodeMANDIRI_label.pack(padx=80, pady=20)

    
    daftarKodeSYARIAH_label = tk.Label(
        daftarKodeframe, text=' SYARIAH  : 666', font=custom_font, anchor='w')
    daftarKodeSYARIAH_label.pack(padx=80, pady=25)

    daftarKodeDANAMON_label = tk.Label(
        daftarKodeframe, text=' DANAMON  : 777', font=custom_font, anchor='w')
    daftarKodeDANAMON_label.pack(padx=80, pady=30)


    daftarKodePERMATA_label = tk.Label(
        daftarKodeframe, text=' PERMATA BANK  : 888', font=custom_font, anchor='w')
    daftarKodePERMATA_label.pack(padx=80, pady=35)

    button_kembalikebanklain = tk.Button(
        daftarKodeframe, text='<-- KEMBALI -->', font=custom_font, command=transfer_window)
    button_kembalikebanklain.pack(padx=80, pady=40)

def backtobanklain():
    daftarKodeframe.pack_forget()
    transfer_window()

### FUNGSi PENARIKAN TUNAI ###

def tariksetorTunai():
    new_labelframe.pack_forget()

    global tarikTunaitampilan_frame
    tarikTunaitampilan_frame = tk.LabelFrame(root, text="")
    tarikTunaitampilan_frame.pack(pady=30)

    tariktunaiframe = tk.Label(
        tarikTunaitampilan_frame, text='Silahkan Memilih Transaksi ', font=custom_font, anchor='w')
    tariktunaiframe.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
    tariktunaiframe = tk.Label(
        tarikTunaitampilan_frame, text='Tekan cancel untuk membatalkan transaksi', font=custom_font,)
    tariktunaiframe.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

    button_tariktunai = tk.Button(
        tarikTunaitampilan_frame, text=' <-- Setor Tunai --> ', font=custom_font, command=setorTunai)
    button_tariktunai.place(x=85, y=150)

    button_tariktunai1 = tk.Button(
        tarikTunaitampilan_frame, text=' <-- Tarik Tunai --> ', font=custom_font, anchor='center')
    button_tariktunai1.pack(padx=10, pady=150)

    button_canceltariktunai = tk.Button(
        tarikTunaitampilan_frame, text='Cancel', font=custom_font, command=closeProgram)
    button_canceltariktunai.pack(padx=10, pady=40)


def setorTunai():
    tarikTunaitampilan_frame.pack_forget()

    global setorTunaiframe
    setorTunaiframe = tk.LabelFrame(root, text="")
    setorTunaiframe.pack(pady=30)

    setortunailabel = tk.Label(
        setorTunaiframe, text='Silahkan Masukan Nominal Yang Ingin di Setor! ', font=custom_font)
    setortunailabel.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
    setor_entry = tk.Entry(setorTunaiframe)
    setor_entry.pack(padx=40, pady=70)

    setortunaiPinlabel = tk.Label(
        setorTunaiframe, text='Masukan Pin : ', font=custom_font)
    setortunaiPinlabel.pack(padx=30, pady=60)
    global setorPin_entry
    setorPin_entry = tk.Entry(setorTunaiframe)
    setorPin_entry.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

    setor_button = tk.Button(setorTunaiframe, text=' Ya ', font=custom_font)
    setor_button.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

    global setor1_button
    setor1_button = tk.Button(
        setorTunaiframe, text='reset', font=custom_font, command=resetsetortunai)
    setor1_button.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

    setor2_button = tk.Button(
        setorTunaiframe, text='cancel', font=custom_font,)
    setor2_button.pack(padx=10, pady=10)


def resetsetortunai():
    setorPin_entry.delete(0, tk.END)


def aftersetor():
    aftersetorlabel = tk.Label(aftersetorlabel, text='')

    root.mainloop()
```

plis help this eror

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).